# Printf pattern matching using variable containing pattern

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, printf

After looking through stackoverflow and others a while ago when creating the script initially, I found this use of printf that did exactly (or so I thought) what I needed:

```
printf '%s\n' '$+?multi_pack?a' "$content" .x | ex $log_output
```

This is as it appears in my script. I know what its outcome is, and roughly how to use printf. This line is adding the string `$content` (which is a command expansion `content="$(cat $temp_file_2)"` where temp_file_2 contains the text I need to append) after the LAST occurance of the pattern 'multi_pack' using the ex text editor. It needs to be the last occurrence because the appending is happening as the log file is being generated (via loops), and multiple occurances of the pattern can occur, but I'm only interested in the last time the pattern appears, thus appending the relevant text (which changes) at each new occurrence of the pattern (which would in turn, would relate to something different from the last pattern matched last time round the loop).

What I'm trying to work out is how to modify the printf command such that the pattern is a variable, and as such change when needed (which would make the position of the text appending change)....

I've tried something like:

```
printf '%s\n' "$+?${my_new_variable}?a" "$content" . x | ex $log_output
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$+?$my_new_variable?a" "$content" . x | ex $log_output
```

and the output isn't what I'd expect....

**EDIT**

The answer by Barmar is what I needed. The question I wanted to ask was 'Was I doing this right?' to help me pinpoint what was causing the output to not work (which, As I explained before Chepner's edit, was possibly not even with this line of code - if it was indeed correct). Printf was a red herring of sorts, Ex is doing the pattern matching.

Comment: Your question is rather verbose.  I think it could be distilled into a much smaller question.  You should show the outputs of the `printf` command — what you get and what you want.

Comment: I've stripped out a good amount of the irrelevant text, but the question could still be much shorter.

Comment: Did the original `printf` command put the `.` and the `x` on separate lines?  I'd expect the `.` on its own to terminate the append operation, and the `x` on its own to exit while writing the file.

Comment: After a little experimentation with the `ex` on MacOS (which behaves appallingly — it clears the screen and tells me I can type 'visual' to go to Normal mode, which is most unpleasant and not what I think it is supposed to do, at all!), the `.` and the `x` should be separate arguments to `printf` to work plausibly at driving `ex`.

Comment: Sorry for verbosity, sometimes I just want to cover as many bases as best I can... the original printf command works exactly as I need other than certain use cases, where, for the sake of clarity, I need to be able to place the appended text more accurately. I can add an example of what currently happens if you feel it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` seems unnecessary for this, use a here-doc:

```
ex $log_output <<EOF
$+?${my_new_variable}?a
$content
.
x
EOF
```

You're less likely to get the line breaks wrong this way.

Comment: Thanks! Answers for various questions get easier to look for when you realise that the printf wasn't doing the pattern searching, ex was.... I have never used the like of ex before, so took the code example I saw and used that.....

Comment: For anyone else looking at this problem in the future. Something I also learned was if the above snippet is added into a code block which has been indented you need to add a '-' to the `<<EOF` (making it `<<-EOF`) to work. Might save people getting the delimiter error, and having to look for that as well!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-nestings-indent?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa